# Joining elements of a nested object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[
  {
    "OrderID": 1,
    "OrderDetails": [
      {
        "OrderDetailID": 7,
    "ProductCode": "E456",
        "Quantity": 1,
      },
      {
        "OrderDetailID": 8,
    "ProductCode": "E888",
        "Quantity": 2
      }
    ],
    "OrderDate": "8/1/2018"
  },
  {
    "OrderID": 2,
    "OrderDetails": [
      {
        "OrderDetailID": 9,
    "ProductCode": "N522",
        "Quantity": 3
      }
    ],
    "OrderDate": "10/1/2018"
  }
]
```

Using JavaScript, I need to concatenate all the `productCodes` into a string so the result should look like this:

```
E456;E888;N522
```

I have tried to use the map function to get `OrderDetails` and was able to do so. But when I chained the map functions again like below, the details variable always returned `undefined` so I cant even call the join function to do the concatenation:

```
var details = this.orderData.map(function(i) {
     return {
         detail: i.OrderDetails
     }}).map(function(j) {
        return {
           x: j.detail.ProductCode
        }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr=[{OrderID:1,OrderDetails:[{OrderDetailID:7,ProductCode:"E456",Quantity:1},{OrderDetailID:8,ProductCode:"E888",Quantity:2}],OrderDate:"8/1/2018"},{OrderID:2,OrderDetails:[{OrderDetailID:9,ProductCode:"N522",Quantity:3}],OrderDate:"10/1/2018"}];

const resp = arr.map(x => x.OrderDetails.map(y => y.ProductCode).join(';')).join(';');

console.log(resp)
```

Comment: This works too, thank you guijob, and I like how simple it looks.  I upvoted but didnt show up due to SE's rules.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.reduce` instead of `.map`, pushing each `ProductCode` to the accumulator array, then join by `;`:

```js
const input = [{
    "OrderID": 1,
    "OrderDetails": [{
        "OrderDetailID": 7,
        "ProductCode": "E456",
        "Quantity": 1,
      },
      {
        "OrderDetailID": 8,
        "ProductCode": "E888",
        "Quantity": 2
      }
    ],
    "OrderDate": "8/1/2018"
  },
  {
    "OrderID": 2,
    "OrderDetails": [{
      "OrderDetailID": 9,
      "ProductCode": "N522",
      "Quantity": 3
    }],
    "OrderDate": "10/1/2018"
  }
];
const productCodes = input.reduce((a, { OrderDetails }) => {
  a.push(...OrderDetails.map(({ ProductCode }) => ProductCode));
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(productCodes.join(';'));
```

Or, on newer browsers or using a polyfill, you can golf it down even more with `flatMap`:

```
const productCodes = input.flatMap(
  ({ OrderDetails }) => OrderDetails.map(
    ({ ProductCode }) => ProductCode
  )
);
```

```js
const input = [{
    "OrderID": 1,
    "OrderDetails": [{
        "OrderDetailID": 7,
        "ProductCode": "E456",
        "Quantity": 1,
      },
      {
        "OrderDetailID": 8,
        "ProductCode": "E888",
        "Quantity": 2
      }
    ],
    "OrderDate": "8/1/2018"
  },
  {
    "OrderID": 2,
    "OrderDetails": [{
      "OrderDetailID": 9,
      "ProductCode": "N522",
      "Quantity": 3
    }],
    "OrderDate": "10/1/2018"
  }
];
const productCodes = input.flatMap(
  ({ OrderDetails }) => OrderDetails.map(
    ({ ProductCode }) => ProductCode
  )
);
console.log(productCodes.join(';'));
```

Comment: That worked thank you CertainPerformance.  I tried looking it up but could you in plain english terms explain what reduce does?

Comment: `.reduce` iterates over an array, the first argument being the accumulator (which is the item returned on the last iteration, or the initial value for the first iteration), and the second argument is the item being iterated over. (The initial argument is specified by the second parameter passed to `.reduce`, which is `[]` here)

Comment: Thank you CertainPerformance.  Still a bit cloudy but definitely helps!